# WPF & Python: getting checkbox values from datatemplate

Tags: python, wpf, user-interface, revit-api, pyrevit

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this, but here goes nothing:

I am creating a wpf window with code behind in Python. I can’t seem to figure out how to get the selected items of my comboboxes though (they are in a DataTemplate).
This is what I have so far, but I can’t seem to get the show_result function to work. Does anyone have any experience with this?

XML:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" MinHeight="450" Width="800" MinWidth="600">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1" x:Name="DataTemplate1">
            <Grid Height="auto" x:Name="GridTemplate">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Area}" x:Name="Area1" Margin="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Verdieping}" x:Name="Verdieping1" Margin="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Gevel}" x:Name="Gevel1a" Margin="3" Grid.Column="2"/>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Gevel}" x:Name="Gevel1b" Margin="3" Grid.Column="3"/>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Gevel}" x:Name="Gevel1c" Margin="3" Grid.Column="4"/>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Gevel}" x:Name="Gevel1d" Margin="3" Grid.Column="5"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Label FontWeight ="Bold" Content="Title Block"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="TitleBlockComboBox" Margin="57,3,3,3" MinWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Label FontWeight="Light" Content=">  selecteer hier een horizontale A3-sheet" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="#7F000000"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Label FontWeight ="Bold" Content="View Template"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="ViewTemplateComboBox" Margin="33,3,3,3" MinWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Label FontWeight="Light" Content=">  view template voor het verdieping plan" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="#7F000000"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Separator Height="5"/>
        <Border Margin="0,10" Background="AliceBlue" CornerRadius="10">
            <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel1" Margin="5">
                <Grid Height="auto" x:Name="Grid1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight ="Bold" Content="Area"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight ="Bold" Content="Verdieping plan"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight ="Bold" Content="Gevel 1"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight ="Bold" Content="Gevel 2"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight ="Bold" Content="Gevel 3"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight ="Bold" Content="Gevel 4"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="AddRowButton" Content="Add Row" Click="AddRow_Click" Margin="0,5,5,5" Width="200"/>
            <Button x:Name="RemoveRowButton" Content="Remove Row" Click="RemoveRow_Click" Margin="5,5,0,5" Width="200"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="show_result" Content="toon resultaat" Click="show_result" Margin="0,5"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Python

```
### IMPORTS ###
from pyrevit import script
from pyrevit import forms
from System.Windows import *
from System.Windows.Controls import *
from rpw.ui.forms import Alert

### GLOBAL PARAMETERS (and temporary lists)###
xamlfile = script.get_bundle_file('ui.xaml')
countCombo = 0
countRows = 0
areasTemp = ["area1", "area2", "area3"]
verdTemp = ["verd0", "verd1", "verd2", "verd3", "verd4"]
gevelTemp = ["gevel1", "gevel2", "gevel3", "gevel4"]
titleBlocksDict = ["tb1", "tb2", "tb3", "tb4", "tb5", "tb6"]
viewTemplatesDict = ["vt1", "vt2", "vt3"]

### DEFINITIONS FOR THE ITEMSOURCES ###
class WPFItems:
    def __init__(self, area, verdieping, gevel):
        self.Area = area
        self.Verdieping = verdieping
        self.Gevel = gevel

GridTemplateData1 = WPFItems(areasTemp, verdTemp, gevelTemp)

### DEFINITIONS TO ADD/REMOVE ROWS ###

def add_row(window):
    global countRows
    countRows += 1
    cc = ContentControl()
    cc.Name = "contentControl{}".format(countRows)
    cc.ContentTemplate = window.Resources["DataTemplate1"]
    cc.Content = GridTemplateData1
    window.StackPanel1.Children.Add(cc)
    return cc

def remove_row(window):
    global countRows
    if countRows > 1:
        countRows -= 1
    num_children = len(window.StackPanel1.Children)
    if num_children > 2:
        last_child = window.StackPanel1.Children[num_children - 1]
        window.StackPanel1.Children.Remove(last_child)

### CREATE THE WINDOW CLASS ###
class MyWindow(forms.WPFWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        forms.WPFWindow.__init__(self, xamlfile)
        self.comboboxes = []
        self.rows = []
        row = add_row(self)
        self.rows.append(row)
        
        #default values
        self.TitleBlockComboBox.ItemsSource = titleBlocksDict
        self.ViewTemplateComboBox.ItemsSource = viewTemplatesDict
    
    def AddRow_Click(self, sender, e):
        row = add_row(self)
        self.rows.append(row)
    
    def RemoveRow_Click(self, sender, e):
        remove_row(self)
        if len(self.rows) > 1:
            del self.rows[-1]
    
    def show_result(self, sender, e):
        result = []
        for row in self.rows:
            temp = row.ContentTemplate.FindName("Area1", row)
            result.append(temp)
        Alert(str(result), "geselecteerde waardes")

### SHOW WINDOW ###
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_window = MyWindow()
    my_window.ShowDialog()
```

When I used only comboboxes, I could easily get the 'SelectedItem'. However, now that I'm using a ContentControl, I can't find the way to get that combobox within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(row, 0)` should give you a reference to the `ContentPresenter` which you can use to get a reference to the root `Grid` in the template:

```
contentPresenter = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(row, 0)
grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(contentPresenter, 0)
```

You could then find the `ComboBoxes` in the `Children` collection of the `Grid`, e.g.:

```
for child in grid.Children:
    ...
```